# Problem converting Alaska to svg because of longitude wraparound

Tags: postgis, svg

I'm trying to render an svg of Alaska, but because the left side of Alaska's longitude is 179 and the right side of Alaska is -152, the left of side Alaska is separated and shows up in the very far right of the svg.

```
SELECT ST_AsSVG(geom,1,1)
FROM states
WHERE state = 'AK'
```

[image: svg screenshot]

Ideally, I would like to just have a 1000x1000 svg and have alaska scaled inside it.

Is there a solution to both these problems?

Comment: Have you tried reprojecting to NAD83 / Alaska Albers or similar?

Comment: If you only need relative coordinates, you could also just add 152 to every longitude, which would not introduce any further distortion or do what @AndreJ says if you need the numbers to be more meaningful.